# Node.js : graceful restarts and server uptime, howto?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've been working on a realtime app using `Node.js` and `Socket.io`, and I'd like to take it from the local testing stage to testing it out with some of our users.  The trouble is, if I close the ssh session to my server it also stops the server I started using `node app.js`

I thought about using `nohup,` but I occasionally get segmentation faults or other random errors that bring down the server.  I need to 1) know when (and hopefully why) my server crashed so I can both work on improving it to crash less and make sure to get it restarted.  Additionally, I can't be awake 24/7 to restart the server myself, so having some sort of `daemon` would be lovely.

I found `forever` available via npm, but it isn't compatible with versions of Node more recent than `0.8.x` and I'm running `0.9.1`, and it doesn't seem like it gets maintained very well.

I also stumbled past `distribution` and `up`, but documentation and examples of building a decent app using them seem lacking.

Then there's this answer using the `cluster` and `os` modules. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10997753/1883464

But Node lists cluster as experimental http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

With the lack of answers, examples, and discussion on keeping Node servers up and running (and updating their code!) in a real production environment I'm starting to feel like I'm the first person to want to take their app to deployment ;)  Somehow I'm sure there are some common answers to this problem I haven't found.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287429/what-is-the-current-best-practice-for-a-production-deployment-of-node-to-aws/14288820#14288820 and specifically the comments about `cluster`'s reliability.

Comment: Also, read this: http://gun.io/blog/tutorial-deploy-node-js-server-with-example/ it uses monit to monitore and restart you node.js app if  it crashes.

Comment: Thanks! @AaronDufour your answer there gives me a little more piece of mind using the cluster method.

Comment: @Kaeros If the Cluster method doesn't work out well I'll try Monit.  Think I like the potential for load balancing Cluster affords.

Comment: What operating system are you serving with? You should use the OS provided init system. We use Ubuntu and Upstart. It works quite well.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.blah ;) Moving to AWS servers in a month though, which is another reason the Cluster answer is probably the best in my case, at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS provided init system provides many advantages over any Node.js module.
Hooking into the init system is the only way to ensure your app starts up automatically after a reboot.

We use Ubuntu and Upstart with a lot of success.
Upstart will restart your application on crash, and can set the user-id/group before running your process. **Do Not Run as Root**.

Writing Upstart files is a bit of a pain, we use [Node Foreman](https://npmjs.org/package/foreman) to automatically generate and export a set of upstart files from our applications `Procfile`.

```
npm i -g foreman
cd MY_APP
nf export -o /etc/init
```

This will place a set of upstart files into `/etc/init` that can be started and stopped with `sudo start foreman` and `sudo stop foreman`.

Upstart is not the only solution here, and the above can be adapted to suit other OSes as needed. On Redhat I recommend looking at `systemd`. I wouldn't recomment using Mac OSX for production, but in a pinch it has `launchd`.

Comment: What's the reasoning on "Do Not Run as Root." Or is that advice only for shared hosting or VPMs?

Comment: If your application has any vulnerabilities, and *all* applications have them, you are over-exposing your system. If you need to bind to port 80, start as root then **drop** your privileges using `process.setuid(...)`.

Comment: Check http://savanne.be/articles/deploying-node-js-with-systemd/ for more info on deploying Node.js with systemd.