# nodejs 'forever' just doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, forever

I am trying to run my nodejs app on an Amazon EC2 instance using forever. I installed nodejs npm, and then ran `sudo npm install forever -g`.
The installation didn't return any errors, so i go ahead and try running my app using `forever start server.js`, but it won't do anything - no output what-so-ever, not even an error.
I also tried `forever --help` and just `forever`, but none of them giving me any response...

When running my app regularly using nodejs - `nodejs init.js` then it works as expected, but i need to get it running using `forever` so it won't shut down when i disconnect from the server.

**Edit :**
Since the only problem i was having was that nodejs was closing when i closed the terminal session to my EC2 server, I solved this by using the linux `nohup` command like this :
`nohup sudo nodejs server.js &`
This kept nodejs running in a child process even after I closed the terminal window.

Thanks for the help though! :)

Comment: Yes, but if the script crasches you have to manually launch it again. How do you manage that?

Answer (score 16):

I was also not receiving any `stdout` input from any `forever` command and this fix nailed it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: woot! this did it for me. hope others find this answer

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help, but as an alternative, you can use `upstart`. Create a script like this:

```
#this is the upstart service task. move it to /etc/init/nodeapp.conf

description "server for Node App"
author "Neels Grobler"

chdir /root/servers/nodeapp
exec node init.js 1>stdout.log 2>stderr.log
respawn
```

And run it by typing `start nodeapp`. To stop type `stop nodeapp`. You can also change the script so that the node app starts on system boot etc. More info at [upstart.ubuntu.com](http://upstart.ubuntu.com)

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `forever start server.js` not just `forever server.js`

Comment: tried that, but it didn't work. I don't get any response from any command starting with 'forever'

Comment: can you write the output of `which forever`

Comment: forever installations are flakey, and if your node is up to date, then forever is broken currently.

Comment: see this discussion and the linked discussions for other solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776587/node-js-graceful-restarts-and-server-uptime-howto

Answer (score 1):

Several guesses.

- If you install using `sudo npm install forever -g`, you might need to `sudo` to run forever.
- Put a full path of server.js when you run forever such as `forever start /home/you/source/server.js` or `sudo forever start /home/you/source/server.js`

Answer (score 1):

On windows, when you run forever like:

```
forever start app.js
```

you can find generated log file in file system at:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.forever\SomeLogFileHere.txt
```

The log files are regenerated for every running script with unique identicator of each file. You can always check which file belongs to which process by:

```
forever list
```