# Sending emails from node server fails when using forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, forever

I have an API server running with Node and the following add user function:

```
add: function (userArray, onSuccess, onError) {
userArray.forEach(function (user) {
    var length = 8,
        charset = "abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }

    var password = retVal;
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    var password = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    user.user_type_id = user.user_type.id;
    if (user.title) {
        user.title_id = user.title.id;
    }
    user.division_id = user.division.id;
    user.password = password;
    user.user_password = retVal;
    user.image_path = 'img/AdamProfil.png';
});

emailTemplates(templatesDir, function (err, template) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var transportBatch = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            host: 'smtp.mail.dk',
            secureConnection: true,
            port: 587,
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            },
            auth: {
                user: 'my@mail.com',
                pass: 'myPassword'
            }
        }));

        var Render = function(locals) {
            this.locals = locals;
            this.send = function(err, html, text) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    transportBatch.sendMail({
                        from: '*** <support@mymail.dk>',
                        to: locals.username,
                        subject: 'Din adgangskode til ***!',
                        html: html,
                        // generateTextFromHTML: true,
                        text: text
                    }, function(err, responseStatus) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(responseStatus.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            this.batch = function(batch) {
                batch(this.locals, templatesDir, this.send);
            };
        };

        // Send multiple emails
        template('password', true, function(err, batch) {
            for(var user in userArray) {
                var render = new Render(userArray[user]);
                render.batch(batch);
            }
        });
    }
});

userArray.forEach(function(user){
    User.create(user)
        .then(function(createdUser) {
            user.profile.user_id = createdUser[null];

            Profile.create(user.profile);
        });
    });
onSuccess(userArray);
}
```

Now when i run my `server.js` file using the console writing `node server.js` and run this function it correctly sends an email to the target (SUCCESS!?) no because when i run this with `forever start server.js` and run the exact same function with the exact same parameters no email is sent.

What the hell is going on?:)

Comment: Although someone might answer from experience, there seems to be no way for anyone other than the author to really test this as is and dig into it.... it is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/); If you need it to run all the time without invoking forever, there's always [upstart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14861375/103081) or [supervisord](http://docs.ghost.org/pl/installation/deploy/)

Comment: You didn't give much information to go on. What version of forever are you using? Are there any relevant messages in the forever logs? Have you tried any troublesoiting at all? If so what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code only, I see a `templatesDir` variable. I'd guess that is different, or changing in an unexpected way, when you run with `forever`.

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/270) at forever. Do you ever reference an absolute path,  or `process.cwd()`?

Worth a try, good luck!